# Why do queries with shorter inverted lists perform better on CPU's when compared to GPU's

Tags: search-engine, cpu, gpu, information-retrieval

Moreover, why do queries with longer inverted list perform better on GPU's?

I read this result in a paper called Using Graphics Processors for High Performance IR querying.

Comment: I don't know anything about the application domain, so take this with a grain of salt, but when I read your question I'm thinking:
Do they? How did you implement them? What are your results? (i.e. how much better do they perform) Or is this a statement you read somewhere? I'm not much help, but perhaps it helps you to rephrase your question. Good luck. ;)

Comment: Please include a link to the paper you site. Also, you might want to swap out some of your tags for benchmarking and testing. And as Bart says, not a lot to go on in your message. How much difference? < 100% or orders-of-magnitude? What search engine will use a GPU for processing? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Queries with longer lists work better on GPUs, because GPUs are highly parallel, and search is a mostly parallel problem.

However, GPUs (and other massively parallel computers) don't process things the same way few-core CPUs do. Like with any other problem, there is non-negligible work to be done to set up the problem for the GPU. For small problem sizes, this overhead swamps out any speedup provided by the GPUs.